# How to compare distributions for observed responses?

Tags: distributions, multiple-regression, panel-data

I performed an experiment in which 37 participants were asked 24 questions and their eye movements were recorded while they solved each question. For each question, I created distributions of a particular eye movement (call it x) over time for participants who answered right and those who answered wrong. I divided each participant's time range into 10 bins (representing 0-10%, 0-20%, 0-30% of time until 0-100% of time). For example, if 10 participants answered a question correctly and 1 out of them had x movement in the first 10% of their time, 2 had x movement within the first 20% of their time, 5 had in the first 30% of their time and so on.., I represented the distribution as (1/10,2/10,5/10....), to get a sort of cumulative distribution function (the last value would be the proportion of participants who have had movement x at all during the course of their time).

For each question, I have two such distribution curves, one for participants who have answered correctly and the other for wrong participants. I want to see whether there is a significant difference between these two distributions. I have looked at multiple regression models and growth curve analysis models. Would they work here? What kind of techniques should I look at?

Answer (score 1):

Your sample size is quite small, so it will be hard to compare CDFs as all tests I know assume $n \rightarrow \infty$ (like one below). In your case I would try doing ANOVA on some statistics. However, if you really want, you can try this idea (but you have to read about its behaviour in low $n$ setting):

You can compare two cumulative distribution functions using the *Kolmongorov-Smirnov Statistic* and performing the two sample Kolmongrov-Smirnov test.

This statistic shows the maximum difference between the two empirical CDFs:

\begin{equation}
K = sup_{z \in \mathbb{R}} |\hat{F}_1(z) - \hat{F}_2(z)|.
\end{equation}

for $n \rightarrow \infty$ the CDF of $\sqrt{n} K$ converges to the CDF

\begin{equation}
R(k) = 1 - \sum_{i = 1}^{+ \infty} (-1)^{i-1} exp(-2i^2k^2).
\end{equation}

I use it in MCMC where n is much larger than in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did check out the Kolmongorov-Smirnov Statistic and will try it out. From what I read, doing a multiple measures ANOVA was what used to be done earlier, but in the research community Multilevel Regression is what is used nowadays. So wanted some insight on that, hence will wait for a few other answers before accepting yours. Cheers!